# Extending two base classes in C# alternative

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I understand you cannot extend two base classes in C#.  What I want to do is ultimately extend the functionality of the default Windows Form class which I cannot do either because it is not open source.

So all my forms have like 5 common functions. There is a ton of redundant code.  On top of this, the problem is spiraling outward because I have other classes that have to call these duplicate functions.

A basic example is as follows.

```
public class A : Form {

   B b;

   public A() {
      b = new B(this);
   }

   private void back() {
      b.go();
   }
}

public class B {

   public void go(Object obj)
   {
      //if obj is of type A
      //call (A) obj.back();
      //if obj is of type C
      //call (C) obj.back();
      //etc...
   }
```

The reason I am passing between classes like this is because it is an MVC application so different functions are suppose to be in different places in order to make this easy to maintain.

As a result of doing it this way, it has made it very very difficult to maintain.  Is there some clever way around this that I haven't though of?

Any suggestions appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Show us an outline of `C` as well.

Comment: For WinForms, also look into MVP as an alternative. And avoid that `Object obj` stuff as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

For this specific problem, Use an interface:

```
interface IGoBackAndForth { void back(); }

public class A : Form, IGoBackAndForth { }
public class C : ..., IGoBackAndForth { }

public void go(Object obj)
{
   var baf = object as IGoBackAndForth;
   if (baf != null) baf.back();
}
```

Comment: Thank you this answered the question as I phrased it perfectly, but I guess I didn't post enough code.  Without posting pages and pages of code its hard to explain the problem.  I actually tried this and rewrote a lot of stuff but it always gets to one point way down the road where a cast needs to be done but it won't allow me:( Thank you though its a perfect answer for the question I asked.

Comment: We can't answer questions that aren't asked. There are similar solutions on larger scales too.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to extend the System.Windows.Forms.Form but also apply your own interface `IHaveAllThoseNavigationFunctions` --or whatever you want to call it.

```
public interface ISupportAllThoseNavigationFunctions
{
    NavigableWindowsForm PreviousLocation { get; set; }

    void go(NavigableWindowsForm destination);
    void back();
}

public partial class NavigableWindowsForm : Form, ISupportAllThoseNavigationFunctions
{
    private NavigableWindowsForm PreviousLocation { get; set; }

    go(NavigableWindowsForm destination)
    {
       //...
    }

    back()
    {
       go(PreviousLocation);
    }
}

public class FormA : NavigableWindowsForm
{
    // todo: implement form A specifics
}

public class FormB : NavigableWindowsForm
{ 
    // todo: implement form B specifics
}
```

This would limit your repetition and expose all your necessary functions within the base class of NavigableWindowsForm which you now own.

Comment: This is awesome response.  This actually crossed my mind but I kind of just figured if I did it that way then VS wouldn't auto generate my design code since I'm dragging and dropping but I hope I was wrong about this I will try it now.